# How to set a count(variable) as a property of a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm currently trying to get the count of all movies that each actor has acted in (neo4j example movie database), and then set that as a `num_movies_acted` attribute for the person node.

So far, I'm able to get a list of all the actors and their respective movie count (including if it's 0 because of the OPTIONAL MATCH)

This is what I have:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
RETURN p.name as name, count(m) as num_movies_acted
```

How would I then set that into the Person Node? I know I should use something like:

`SET p.num_movies_acted = count(m)`, but that fails to work.

```
Invalid use of aggregating function count(...) in this context (line 3, column 26 (offset: 84))
"SET p.num_movies_acted = count(m)"
```

EDIT: Would this work?

```
MATCH (p:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH p, count(m) as num_movies_acted
SET p.num_movies_acted = num_movies_acted
RETURN p
```

since I am "storing" the count(m) into a variable first

Comment: I don't have an answer, but this seems to create additional problems+complexity. what are you trying to solve for? if you do find a way to set a property, you will also need a way for the property to auto-update as the data changes, otherwise the property value will drift from actual (a bit like data caching in general, how will you update the cached value?). for example: you might set `num_movies_acted=4`, then another movie is added to the graph, and actual count is now 5; how does `num_movies_acted` change to reflect 5?

Comment: Using `WITH` is the way to do it, but I agree somewhat with Kaan, that you might be opening a can of worms by relying on a stored count to be accurate.
It might be better just to count the `:Movie` nodes in real time when you need to. Counting nodes/relationships is much more efficient in Neo4j than it is with an RDBMS as the relationships are created when their end nodes are stored, not at query time as in an RDBMS.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't recognize the time complexity problems prior to this. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MATCH (p:Person) OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie) RETURN
> p.name as name, count(m) as num_movies_acted

This query returns a list as num_movies_acted, which fails to work when you try to set it as an property of an individual node.

> EDIT: Would this work?
>
> MATCH (p:Person) OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie) WITH p,
> count(m) as num_movies_acted SET p.num_movies_acted = num_movies_acted
> RETURN p

Yes this would work fine as you are counting the Movie node for each of the Person node and setting the property.

You can also try:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH p, count(r) as num_movies_acted
SET p.num_movies_acted = num_movies_acted
RETURN p
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a note for someone expecting a tree with an aggregation property.

I need a tree( Person-[ACTED_IN]->Movie ) with p.num_movies_acted,
so finally I got a cypher:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
  WHERE m.released > 2000
  WITH p, count(r) as num_movies_acted
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
  WHERE m.released > 2000
SET p.num_movies_acted = num_movies_acted
RETURN p,r,m
```

I got the same error of aggregation, so tried to somehow avoid it.
I'm not confident in it. So, kindly tell me more efficient one.